# Error when trying to execute a command in java

Tags: java, terminal, runtime, execution

I am trying to run a java file using the terminal but from java. Meaning, I'll run the command using java.
I am trying to execute the command 'cd /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src ' that redirects to the following directory and then execute the command 'ls' that lists all the files in the current directory

I am using this method to run the Java file 'NewFile.java'

```
 try {
           String line;
           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cd /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src" );
           Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "ls" );

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()) );
           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
           }
           in.close();

     }
     catch (Exception e) {
           // ...
         }
```

**The output**

> Directly using the terminal -> It gives 'NewFile.java'
>
> Using this method using Java -> It always give 'bin' and 'src' for whatever command given to **p2**

Here are several trials

> Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ **cd
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src**
>   Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$ **java NewFile**   5  90  35  45  150  3
>   Reichweite---- nach blase art
>       3  5  35  45  90  150
>
> Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$ **java /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile**
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   .Users.apple.Documents.Documents.workspace.UserTesting.src.NewFile    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>
> Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$ **java
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile.java**
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile/java
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   .Users.apple.Documents.Documents.workspace.UserTesting.src.NewFile.java
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>   Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$
>   Blockquote

Comment: Too difficult to understand your problem. You need to do present it better

Comment: Here is a much better explanation @JunedAhsan

Comment: @BrianRoach It is different, here I want to run a Java file from inside java using the commands we use in the terminal

Comment: Which the answer to that question explains. Your process *is not a terminal*. You can't change the working directory by exec'ing an external process. And that's ignoring that exec'ing `ls` instead of simply reading the directory is rather silly in the first place.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. If you want to execute a java file why the cd/ls? Why not just `java /path/to/file.class`? Also this program should not even run correctly (`cd` is not an application), so it should not print anything at all.

Comment: because simply this doesn't work !

Comment: Even in the terminal you have to redirect first and then 'java FileName'

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems the problem you're having is that you don't understand why you get different results when you invoke the program in different ways.

Here's what's going on:  `Runtime.geRuntime().exec()` creates a new process, which is a child of the parent.  Every process has its own working directory; when you fork a new process, it inherits the working directory of the parent.  Invoking `cd` will then change the working directory of the current process (and this is a shell builtin, but ignore that for now and I'll get to it later).

So what you're doing is this:

> Parent
>
> -> create child 1 -> change working directory of child 1
>
> -> create child 2 -> invoke "ls"

Note that child 2 will inherit the working directory of its parent.  It won't know anything about the working directory of child 1.  So depending on the working directory of the process that is invoking this method (in your case, either the terminal or...I don't know, your JDK install?) you will get different results.

If you want the same results every time, you could do something like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "ls /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src" );
```

And if you want to be able to exec your program from anywhere, just use the full path:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "java /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/NewFile" );
```

(assuming, of course, that you have already used `javac` to build `NewFile.class` in that directory, and that you have the right permissions to execute it.)

Re: `cd`, as I mentioned before this is a command that's built into your shell.  When you invoke the command using `exec` in this way, it is likely failing.  You can check on that by reading standard error using the `getErrorStream()` method of `Process`.

Comment: I am just using ls for testing .. I want to run the java file 'NewFile' using this method

Comment: The full path of the file is /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile.java

Comment: Did you see the change I suggested?  The same way you can pass the full (rather than relative) path to `ls`, you can also pass the full path to exec.  Edited my answer to provide the code.

Comment: Please check several trials updated in my question @danben

Comment: I mean, now you're just pasting unrelated errors into your question.  I answered what you originally asked about.

Comment: you specifically wrote this 'java /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/NewFile' which I tried and showed you that it is not working .. that's why I posted this\

Comment: Sorry, SO isn't tech support.  Read the error message.